# Java Matching And Parsing String

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to parse this string.  I want to return the word that has .prm appended to it and then everything else after the :.  I am struggling with the Pattern and Matching classes in Java.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
This is the statement to remove, CAPTURETHIS.prm:  WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!
```

Help please

Comment: Do you mean `String[] matches = text.split("\\.pm", 2);` ?

Comment: No, I don't want anything but CAPTURETHIS.prm and the part that follows the :

Comment: @Jarod you said you want to capture the part after the : also.

Comment: Do you mean `String[] matches = text.split("\\.prm:", 2);` ?

Comment: Without knowing some characteristics of `CAPTURETHIS` it's tough to do.  Can you state that whatever is in `CAPTURETHIS` will, for instance, never contain a space?

Comment: That returns everything leading up to prm:.... I just want the <CAPTURETHIS> and then what follows the : nothing leading up to <CAPTURETHIS> and not the .prm.

Comment: <CAPTURETHIS> is a file name and will never have a space

Comment: Will it always be preceded by at least one space?

Comment: Yes just like in the question, it will always be that format.  There will be a comma "," then the name I am interested in <CAPTURETHIS> followed with a .prm: and then a space for the rest of the text I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```
String s="CAPTURETHIS.prm: WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!".
String[] str=s.split(".prm:");
String s1=str[0];
String s2=str[1];
```

s1 has `"CAPTURETHIS"` and s2 `WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!`.

Comment: The string is dynamic that is getting loaded in and there is text prior to the .prm that I need to strip off.  Can you tell me how to get rid of everything leaving up to CAPTURETHIS.prm without knowing what CAPTURETHIS will always be?

Answer (score 0):

If `CAPTURETHIS` never contains a space  and is preceded by at least one whitespace character, then the following regex will do it

```
.*\s(\S+\.prn:.*)
```

Note that if the pattern `something.prn:` occurs more than once in the line this will capture only the last one.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\s(\\S+\\.prn:.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
else
    /* no match */;
```

Comment: can you show me an example of the code?  I am trying to use this with the Pattern class and it isn't compiling

Comment: That doesn't compile giving an invalid escape sequence

Comment: Sorry, missed a backslash.  All regex backslashes must be doubled in a Java string.

Comment: This just prints the whole string right back to me not stripping anything off the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't expect the "xxxx.prm" to be at the start of the line and that it should have no embedded whitespace,

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\.prm:.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
    if (m.find()) {
       matched = m.group();
    }
```

This finds the substring consisting of:

- one-or-more non-whitespace characters
- ".prm:"
- zero-or-more characters after the ":"

The `matched` string is the result.

(I thought about using negative look-behinds and other things ... but I twigged that it is unnecessary since the initial `\S+` will be greedy.  Likewise, the $ and ^ anchors are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String testString = "CAPTURETHIS.prm: WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!";
    String[] splittedByColon = testString.split(":");

    for (String word : splittedByColon[0].split(" ")) {
        if(word.endsWith(".prm")){
            builder.append(word.split(".prm")[0]);
        }
    }

    if(splittedByColon.length > 1)
        builder.append(splittedByColon[1]);

    return builder.toString();
```

Comment: As I have said in the above post, the testString in your example is dynamic, I will always have a <CAPTURETHIS>.prm in the string and I need to cut everything prior to it.

Comment: But every prior word without .prm suffix won't be added to builder

Comment: But I also want .prm stripped off of it

Answer (score 0):

Same as Devavrata's answer but with a couple of lines added to remove the unwanted statement

```
String s="This is the statement to remove, CAPTURETHIS.prm:  WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!".
String[] str1=s.split(".prm:");
String before=str[0];
String after=str[1];
String[] str2=before.split(" ");
String fileName=str2[str2.length-1];
```

**fileName** wil contain *CAPTURETHIS* and **after** will contain *WANT TO CAPTURE THIS MESSAGE TOO!*.